# Error when i load and create video in Django

Tags: python, django

My function in django will receive a video from my site, it's saving normally. I create a function `create`:

```
   def create(self, request):
       Video.objects.create(file=request.data['file'], creator=self.request.user)
       return Response('ok')
```

I'll define the function by my way. But when i load a file from disk: `request.data['file'] = open('/home/developer/Pictures/teste.webm')` it's giving me an error when i create the object:

```
   def create(self, request):
       request.data['file'] = open('/home/developer/Pictures/teste.webm')
       Video.objects.create(file=request.data['file'], creator=self.request.user)
       return Response('ok')
```

OutPut: `*** TypeError: readonly attribute`

So i verify the type of my variables.

```
(Pdb) type(request.data['file'])
<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>
(Pdb) request.data['file'] = open('/home/developer/Pictures/teste.webm')
(Pdb) type(request.data['file'])
<type 'file'>
```

Ok, i know now the types are different, but how i turn my local file in `<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>`

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't write into the request dictionary. And you can't just pass a stream to a file field in Django. You have to do something similar to following:

```
def create(self, request):
    from django.core.files import File
    file = File(open('/home/developer/Pictures/teste.webm', mode='rb'), name='my_file.png')
    Video.objects.create(file=file, creator=self.request.user)
    return Response('ok')
```

It's better to use Django forms to handle model data for these purposes. I am not sure if you can simply pass file like this to a model instance. Never tried this before in this way.

Comment: Same error. The problem is he's trying write the file. But here it's readonly.

Comment: Can you try to open the file in binary? `file = open('/home/developer/Pictures/teste.webm', 'rb')`

Comment: Same error, the problem is the `file` must be a django file.

Comment: @ViniciusMorais I changed my answer. Have a look.